# How to automatically reload a jsp based on other page action

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a situation that i can't handle and thats why need your help.
I have a jsp page (mention as A in below pic) where there are many rows and each of them can be edited. 
At the end of the A jsp page, there is an option to print the page data.
Now, if some body clicks on the edit link/button, another page will open contain the data for that particular row and user can modify the data in the second page(i,e B).
Now, i want, as soon as the user save the B page, A page should be refreshed automatically to provid the updated data for printing.

Please guide me on how to acheive that . I'm using Spring MVC framework for the java application.
[image: Graphical Example]

Comment: You can open popup window whenever a clcik is happen on edit button. onclick open window having that URL to your new JSP. Or simply you can open new page in that frame  whenever clicks on edit button

Comment: Why not you try to look for ajax call to achieve the same, like when u click on `save and close` just try to reload..

Comment: @SaviNuclear reloading what? B page is completely seperate page than A

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved like this. Follow the steps mentioned

1] When you click on edit button in Page A, pass the id of the row to Page B as request parameter.

2]In Page B JSP receive the id of the row and store it in a hidden element.

3]Create a JavaScript function in Page A which should receive row Id and  Modified data as parameter. Lets name it this function as updateRows(rowId,modifiedData). In this function write code to update the  with id 'rowId' with modified data using javascript

4]Now When you click on 'Save & Close' Button in Page  B. Save the data using call to server. If save succeeds then invoke the function updateRows passing it rowId stored in hidden element and modified data as parameters. This function will  update the DOM with latest data.

This way you will avoid making server call to refresh the data

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kugve. But.. at point 4,you mentioned 'Save the data using call to server'.. how ? That is supposed to be a html form submit and after submitting, the window will be closed, now how would i retrieve the updated data in a js method that is to be invoked from another page?(as you said 'If save succeeds then invoke the function updateRows passing it rowId stored in hidden element '). i'm confused

Comment: To achieve  this you need to make AJAX call to the server so that  you can handle  the response.  Is there any reason you don't want to do AJAX call here?

Comment: As I mentioned this must be done using script. Server won't be having any idea which window to send response. With AJAX you can easily do this. I have done similar requirement in my project using  AJAX with above mentioned steps

Answer (score 0):

The Spring MVC way to meet your requirement is:

- the `Edit` buttons in page A should be links calling page B with the id of the line to edit, something like `<a href="$pageBUrl?id=$rowId" class="editButton">Edit</a>`
- the `SaveAndClose` button in page B should be a submit button that posts the edited values to a controller method. After server side processing, the controller method should *redirect* to page A. As a side effect, you use the [PostRedirectGet pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) which avoids the ugly *do you want to send again ... ?"*

  ```
  @RequestMapping(path = "...", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String saveAndClose(...) {
      ...
      return "redirect:/path/to/pageA";
  }
  ```

Of course this will display all pages in same window.

If you want to redisplay the window containing pageA on the `Save & Close` from page B, still allowing the save to be known to the server, you should redirect to a special page (say pageC) that just contains javascript code asking the browser to redisplay pageA. You can either pass the name of the window containing pageA in a hidden field, or you can decide that *as the programmer of the web application* you know where it should be.

Comment: Thank you Serge. I know all of its procedure that you mentioned. I was not sure that of i use redirect, it will refresh the already opened A page. Let me try.

Comment: @user3378974: This procedure only works if pageA and pageB open in same browser window. If you use different windows, you will have to use client side javascript, because the server cannot know about your local windows.

Comment: As i thought, It doesn't serve my purpose.It doesn't refresh the page A, it opens refreshed page A in the B window. But I want the previously opened A page should have refreshed and B page closed.

Comment: Can you please give an example or dummy idea?@Serge

Comment: @user3378974: See my edit. But I cannot help you further in that direction, because I am far from a JavaScript expert :-( . IMHO, if you do not know how to do the javascript part, you should ask a new question tagged javascript, refering to this one for context and explaining where you are now stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way if you don't want to use ajax.

In Page A define a javascript function refreshPageA(). In this function add page refreshing logic. 
When you click on 'Save & Close' button in Page B save the data  in server and forward to a plain jsp. In this  JSP declare a onload handler. Inside onload handler add following code

`opener.refreshPageA();
 window.close()`
 
This  will refresh pageA and close page B window